# Sending Notification using OneSignal Nodejs

Tags: node.js, onesignal

I'm trying to send push notification using OneSignal Node.js API, I'm targeting specific devices so I'm using the include_player_ids field, here is the code:

```
    function sendPushNotification(token,text){
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        if(token === undefined || token === null){
            return res({});
        }

        let token_array = [];
        token_array.push(token);

        const notification = {
            contents: {
              'en': text,
            },
            include_player_ids:token_array
        };

        return client.createNotification(notification).then(response => {
            return res(response)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            return rej(e);
        });

    })
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "message": "[object Object]",
  "code": "500",
  "data": {
    "body": {
      "errors": [
        "Message Notifications must have English language content"
      ]
    },
    "statusCode": 400
  }
}
```

Here is the documentation: but I'm having some trouble: [Node js api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onesignal-node)

Thanks!

Comment: Try to console.log(text) to check null or empty.

Comment: Thanks, somehow sometimes, the function was called with a null text.

Answer (score -1):

Yes the problem comes from below line

```
'en': text
```

Use this instead

```
'en' : 'text'
```